# What is the difference between assembly language of x86 and x64 architecture?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I am studying this book [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593270070) . Now it says repeatedly to use a x86 processor cause its source code's are based on x86. But My laptop is of type amd64 . So I want to know how much is the difference. Can I continue reading the book and understand?

Comment: You should be fine as long as you build 32-bit applications rather than 64-bit applications.

Comment: Currently there is no virtual box for Ubuntu-13.10 :(

Comment: @Alex: no need. There are many flavors of 64-bit Linux that run 32-bit code just fine (Debian, RedHat). So does 64-bit Windows.

Comment: Just to prevent confusion - AMD64 (and Intel64) are indeed x86-64, and are not to be confused with IA-64 that was used by the Itanium family.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actual 64 bit programs use a different instruction set (though it has a strong family resemblance). But that doesn't need to concern you, as it's backwards compatible: 32 bit code runs just fine, if you don't attempt to compile it as 64 bit code.

Comment: That answer is not great ... The instruction set as well as the binary encoding in 32bit x86 and 64bit x86 is pretty much _identical_ apart from the use of new _instruction prefixes_ in 64bit mode (and the retirement of 1-byte `dec`/`inc` opcodes resp. the reinterpretation of those as prefixes); prefix bytes have been a feature of x86 since its inception. The differences between 64bit x86 and 32bit x86 are, if anything, smaller than those between 32bit x86 and 16bit x86 ... and yes, it is possible to create x86 binary code that runs identically in both 32bit and 64bit mode.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just starting programming, then I would not worry too much about it.  The first thing that comes to mind is the use of threading and how there would be small differences there.

However, I assume that you are starting out and wanting to jump right into "hacking".  This can quite simply not happen.  You need to understand that hacking is built upon the very base building blocks of programming.  While there are many programs out there that can be run to do things like packet sniffing and such, there are nearly useless to those that do not know what to do with them.

I am going out on a limb with some of these assumptions and I could be wrong, but most people that grab up a book like this do not have the background knowledge.  If you want to learn "hacking", start with the basics.  Look up and use "Linux from Scratch" to build an operating system from scratch.  That is a good basic start.  Learn languages like C and C++ and not languages like Visual Basic.  These will help you understand that basics of how programs are built and run.

I know that the last time that we did "Linux from Scratch" for fun, there were several small errors in the documentation that are no big deal when you know what you are doing, but a noob would simply copy and paste the commands and find themselves scratching their heads when something goes wrong.  Start at the beginning, it is the way to go.

Comment: I am quite familiar with C and C++ and linux OS. and I didn't just jumped into this book other night. Many books I didn't bought just because those just explain how to use softwares, not to build them. I thought through this book I can gain the knowledge both about OS and networking, currently I am following this tutotial about linux.http://linuxtutorial.info/

Comment: That's cool.  It is just common to see people grab something like that and think they are going to become a hacker overnight.  They watch a couple movies and think that it is all fun and no work.  They never show the hours and hours of command line work and waiting.  Well, it showed a little of that in "Takedown", lol.

Answer (score 1):

I think x64 is the name for the architecture for the extensions to the x86 instruction set that enable 64-bit code.

`x86` basically means Intel `80x86` compatible.

You can also check [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)

Comment: [AMD](http://www.amd.com) also has programmers reference manuals that are worth looking at, especially if you actually have an AMD chip and need to know how it differs from a similar Intel chip...

Comment: (fyi GNU and most other non wintel sources seem to call it x86_64, or even still amd64. The original name (by AMD) was AMD64, but that of course didn't run very well with Intel. Intel called its implementation "intel 64" for a while. Afaik x64 is mostly used by Microsoft. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Industry_naming_conventions). It's all (nearly) the same thing, as long as you don't say IA64, everything is fine.